# chrome.extension.executeScript( code : ) work, but not with (file : )

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension for chrome which have a popup, 
in the popup i have a button, which when pressed, append a black div in the
current tab body.

So in my popup.html, theres link to jquery, and to my popup.js. I have also content_scripts which loads jquery in the current browser tab

code of popup.js :

```
   $('div.enable').on('click', function(){
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
     { code : "$('body').append('<div class="test"></div>');"} );
   });
```

This is working, But if i try to put my code in an external file,like this:

popup.js:

```
      $('div.enable').on('click', function(){
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
             { file : "manipulateDOM.js"} );
           });
```

manipulateDOM.js :

```
       $('body').append('<div class="test"></div>');
```

i cant get it to work, all the files are at the root of the extension. I can't see what i'm missing. And i 'd like to understood

*************** EDIT ******************

i will try to make a git to better explain the problem

thanks again

Comment: Do you have jQuery injected first into the tab in question? The first code snippet might be using Chrome's whatever-is-used-for-console, but apriori you have no jQuery in your script's context. Besides, is there any output in the tab's console?

Comment: @user3575902 your first code can't work as is because quotes aren't properly escaped. Please make sure the code you post here is the same you are testing.

Comment: @Xan the questions says: "I have also content_scripts which loads jquery in the current browser tab"

Comment: @rsanchez We can't be sure OP's jQuery inject is _working_. The console(s) need to be inspected to confirm.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answers, it's the first time i ask on stackoverflow .. No there's no output in console ...

     chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
          { code : "alert('stacking')" }
     );

this is working ...

but not if i put the same alert in an external file . i dont think it's a jQuery problem